# mysql query filter rows based on a constant column value and a varying boolean column

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table

| Cat | User | Active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 45 | 0 |
| 12 | 54 | 0 |
| 13 | 76 | 0 |
| 12 | 33 | 1 |
| 15 | 66 | 0 |
| 12 | 12 | 0 |
| 12 | 22 | 0 |

I run a query to select based on category id(cat).

fore ex. If I am querying for cat 12 then the rows with active 1 should be the result even if there are rows with active=0.

| Cat | User | Active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 33 | 1 |

If active= 1 is not present and if there are active = 0 then the rows with active=0 should be the result.

| Cat | User | Active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 45 | 0 |
| 12 | 54 | 0 |
| 12 | 12 | 0 |
| 12 | 22 | 0 |

Hope it should be possible to do all these in one single query with IF.
But, I could not figure out. Need help.

Thanks

Comment: Something like this should probably work: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE cat = 12 AND active = (SELECT LEAST(COUNT(*), 1) FROM table WHERE cat = 12 AND active = 1)` The subquery simply counts the number of records with active=1, and selects the minimum of that count, and 1. So if there are any active records, say five of them, the min of (5, 1) is 1, and the main query will select all records with active=1. Or that count is 0, then the min of (0, 1) will be 0, and the main query will select all records with active=0.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM test t1
JOIN (SELECT cat, MAX(active) AS active
      FROM test
      GROUP BY cat) AS subquery USING (cat, active)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bqwFMGNL)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is on your `WHERE` clause check the `COUNT()` of `Active` rows and depending on the number perform the appropriate equality. For example:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM your_table_name
    WHERE Cat = 12 AND Active = (CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table_name WHERE Cat = 2 AND Active = 1)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/4K8DHHmw